# How to monitor Windows file/disk activities, and filter them?

Tags: windows-7

A huge amount of data is getting deleted from one of my drives (50 MB per minute, 2-3 GB per hour).

I would like to know what program is deleting which files.

Process usage in Task Manager doesn't help (no suspicious activity there).

How can I monitor this file/disk activity?

Comment: Have you enabled auditing on the impacted folder(s)? Then you could review the resulting event log entries to determine what or who is carrying out the deletion. There is additional overhead in doing this but will give you historical data if you are only turning on for a short time. Otherwise SysInternals Process Explorer could capture some of this information for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sysinternals Process Monitor is probably the best tool for what you describe. If run without filters, it will capture an astonishing amount of data - even when sitting mostly idle, Windows still does occasional work in the background - but you can easily check for actions involving a specific file.

You could also use Process Explorer (also from Sysinternals, now part of Microsoft) like @Enigman suggested, or Resource Monitor (`resmon.exe`, built into Windows) to see what processes are opening your file. There will be a list of all open HANDLEs; you can search it (in resmon, go to the CPU tab to find the "Associated Handles" list).